# Gauss Bonnet failure

Tags: numerical-integration, differential-geometry

This is a follow-up to [this question:](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144591/computing-the-topological-genus-from-a-parametric-function)The OP asks how to compute the genus (or Euler characteristic) of a parametrized surface in $\mathbb{R}^3.$ One of the commenters recommends the Gauss-Bonnet formula, which I pooh-poohed in my answer, but then thought that I should try it before heaping scorn. Luckily, the code to compute Gauss curvature is given in [another MSE post.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61409/computing-gaussian-curvature) and implementing this, one gets the following formula for the Gauss curvature of the torus given by

```
ParametricPlot3D[
{Cos[x] + .4 Cos[x] Sin[y], Sin[x] + .4 Sin[x] Sin[y], Cos[y]}, 
{  x, 0, 2 π}, {y, 0, 2 π}]
```

(this was one of the examples in the first referenced question).

Sure enough, I got:

```
(-0.260682 + 0.264024 Cos[2 y] - 0.00334208 Cos[4 y] - 
0.568153 Sin[y] + 0.0501312 Sin[3 y])/(-0.78609 + 1. Cos[2 y] - 
0.264011 Cos[4 y] + 0.0235115 Cos[6 y] - 0.000147386 Cos[8 y] - 
1.26981 Sin[y] + 0.56683 Sin[3 y] - 0.0988186 Sin[5 y] + 
0.00294771 Sin[7 y])
```

which seems reasonable, but then NIntegrating it over the parameter space $[0, 2 \pi] \times [0, 2 \pi]$ gives $-8.59435,$ which, whatever else it might be, is not zero. It *is* however, $-27/\pi.$ Would anyone care to explain what the heck is going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you did is quite close, it's just missing the area form.

We have the parametrization below.

```
xyz[x_, y_] := {Cos[x] + .4 Cos[x] Sin[y], Sin[x] +
  .4 Sin[x] Sin[y], Cos[y]};
```

Define the derivatives with respect to parameters.

```
dxyz = Transpose[{D[xyz[a, b], a], D[xyz[a, b], b]}]
```

Recalling that `dx = D[x,a]*da + D[x,b]*db` (and apologies for mixing differential forms notation with Mathematica), and the area form is the sum of the three edge products of distinct differentials from `{dx,dy,dz}`, with orientation taken into account I believe this is:

```
areaD = Det[dxyz[[1 ;; 2]]] + Det[dxyz[[2 ;; 3]]] + 
  Det[dxyz[[{3, 1}]]]
```

Changing variables to `{a,b}` notation, and setting `gc` to the expression for Gauss curvature, I get:

```
-1/(2*Pi)*NIntegrate[gc*areaD, {a, 0, 2*Pi}, {b, 0, 2*Pi}]

During evaluation of In[389]:= NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

During evaluation of In[389]:= NIntegrate::eincr: The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 2000 times. The global error is expected to decrease monotonically after a number of integrand evaluations. Suspect one of the following: the working precision is insufficient for the specified precision goal; the integrand is highly oscillatory or it is not a (piecewise) smooth function; or the true value of the integral is 0. Increasing the value of the GlobalAdaptive option MaxErrorIncreases might lead to a convergent numerical integration. NIntegrate obtained -5.60142210393*10^-15 and 1.9833450181266685`*^-11 for the integral and error estimates.

(* Out[389]= 8.91494016185*10^-16 *)
```

So either I made a mistake in the area form, or this vindicates your approach.

Comment: You are right, of course, it was late at night, but still stupid to forget the area form.

Comment: However, the fact that the integral is exactly $-27/\pi$ is kind of cool and mysterious.

Comment: Yeah. But that's what made me think an area form might be missing: the appearance of pi sort of signalling a parametrization issue.